# How to separate the editText cursor position from position of android:hint?

Tags: xml, user-interface, android

This is my EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="25"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:hint="Type note here" />
```

The position of the hint is in the center and I have achieved that using android:gravity="center". I want my text to be entered from top-left but this is not happening because of the gravity. Is there any way I can do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can monitor when text is enter using a `TextWathcer` and then change the gravity of your `TextView` to your desired one:

```
textEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int start, int before, int count)
    {
         textEdit.setGravitiy("to what ever you want");
    }

});
```

you may want to check if the edittext is empty or not before doing those changes.

Comment: It works when the editText.setGravity() is done in the onTextChange() instead of the beforeTextChanged()..Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programatically by changing the gravity of the `EditText` when it's clicked. Example (not sure it works exactly, didn't test it):

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

});
```

Comment: Tried changing programatically like the way you have mentioned but this does not work.